# Custom ListView set Background Drawable in XML doesnt work

Tags: android, listview

I'm getting frustrated about this:

When I define a custom ListView Layout,

Android Studio doesn't keep the background drawable I set in there.

Tried many things, and setting background programmatically doesn't work

since it's ignoring the layout_width which must be set to "wrap_content".

[Actual style of background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SGMSl.jpg)

[Result without coding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/98yBt.jpg)

If anyone could help me, I'd be very grateful !:)

EDIT:

I'm creating a Messenger and I want to display messages in a similar way to WhatsApp, where messages are shown in a listView. Depending on message is sent or received, items should be aligned ParentStart or ParentEnd.

But more importantly, if a message only contains a few chars, I don't want the ListItem Background to fill the entire screen, so it should be set dynamically. 
I thought I could achieve this through simply setting wrap content in the parent layout file.

Files look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    tools:background="@drawable/background_message_sent">

    //Here are TextViews

</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is my ListViewAdapter, where I set background

(@drawable/background_message_sent/received) programmatically.

However, this covers the entire width of ListView, regardless of message length.

```
@Override
public View getView(int pos, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


    int currentUserID = 1;
    int senderID = messagesArrayList.get(pos).getSenderID();

    if (senderID == currentUserID){

        View v = View.inflate(context, R.layout.layout_chat_message_sent, null);
        v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background_message_sent);
        TextView tvMessageText = v.findViewById(R.id.tvMessageText);
        TextView tvTimeStamp = v.findViewById(R.id.tvTimeStamp);

        tvMessageText.setText(messagesArrayList.get(pos).getMessageText());
        tvTimeStamp.setText(messagesArrayList.get(pos).getTimeStamp());
        return v;
    }
    else {
        View v = View.inflate(context, R.layout.layout_chat_message_received, null);
        v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background_message_received);
        TextView tvMessageText = v.findViewById(R.id.tvMessageText);
        TextView tvTimeStamp = v.findViewById(R.id.tvTimeStamp);

        tvMessageText.setText(messagesArrayList.get(pos).getMessageText());
        tvTimeStamp.setText(messagesArrayList.get(pos).getTimeStamp());
        return v;

    }
}
```

Comment: Result with coding: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pljUc.jpg

Comment: It's little bit confusing what you want. You want space between listview items or?

Comment: Thank you for your quick response.
I just want that original layout I designed for ListView Items in my lvitems.xml to be shown propperly in the ListView.
I'll edit my original post.

Comment: You actually no need `ListView` to implement chat if you have of course server side logic. `ScrollView` with `TextView` or `LinearLayout` casted would work just fine. And background with padding on the `TextView` could reslove the issue background streching all over the screen. That way it would wrap up just text.

Comment: I'm kinda new to all this, but I'm saving messages sent and received in SQLite so it doesn't stream all day long right?

I could imagine now TextView in ScrollView, you mean programmatically creating new ones for each message?

Comment: For example you have `ScrollView` inside it `LinearLayout` then create a `TextView` programmaticaly and then get the value from user input which is probably from `EditText` and add `TextView` to the `Linearlayout` with `addView` method. And you will have your messages verticali sorted inside `LinearLayout` with background wrapped up just around text. But why SQLite? How chat will work with inner phone database?

Comment: Okay thanks for pointing to this alternative way! 
I'm not using phone data and contacts. 
This app will be working with user accounts only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after trying, I got the solution if anyone comes to this point:

You have to set your background drawable directly for each TextView, not for Parent Layouts.
These two Lines finally solved everything ^^

```
android:maxEms="14" 
android:background="@drawable/background_message_sent"

        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvMessageText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.22"
        android:text="42456456456546"
        android:textColor="@color/tentakelPrimary"
        android:maxEms="14"
        android:background="@drawable/background_message_sent"/>
```